# Differential topology book

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, self-learning

I want to self-study differential topology. I'd like to hear suggestions from you about appropriate books that I could use while studying.

Note: I have not studied differential topology before. I self-studied general topology and some algebraic topology before.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A standard introductory textbook is *Differential Topology* by Guillemin and Pollack. It was used in my introductory class and I can vouch for its solidity. You might also check out Milnor's *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint* and *Morse Theory.* (I have not read the first, and I have lightly read the second.)

For other books on topology, Hatcher has a nice list [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/topologybooks.pdf). You may be interested in books like Bott-Tu or others listed under item III, manifold theory.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. For the first book that you mentioned, am I missing any of its prerequisites ?

Comment: @Amr Have you studied analysis and measure theory, enough to be familiar with Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: I did, but I did not go to deep. I studied measure theory from an analysis book. There were 2 chapters on measure theory. I did not study a pure measure theory book. Is this OK ?

Comment: I am familiar with lesbesgue integrals as well.

Comment: What you need is a multivariable analysis course -- familiarity with the derivative as a linear map, chain rule, inverse/implicit function theorems. You don't need any abstract measure theory, although the notion of measure zero will show up.